# How to prevent or verify the input value aginst the data list?

Tags: angularjs

I have converted a `input` element as a drop down menu. all this works other than a issue i am facing.

When user instead of selecting some `month` from my `data-list`, if they type something like 'foo` still my input field and form considers the value as valid.

so, i would like to verify the value what the user entered with my existing array of months. if the user not enter the value which is not existing in the list, still i would like to consider the value as invalid.

how to test the user entered value against my data list?

here is my code and plunker:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.months = [
                "January", "February", "March", 
                "April", "May", "June", "July",  
                "August", "September", "October",
                "November", "December"
            ];

  $scope.defaultMonth = '';

  $scope.showList = false;

  $scope.setFocus = function() {
    $scope.showList=true;
  }

  $scope.setMonth = function ( month ) {
    $scope.defaultMonth = month;
    $scope.showList=false;
  }



});
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/V77haIuQ6hxRPSmxYA3F?p=preview)

Comment: Just to clarify: You would like to have the input field display as invalid if the user types in something that doesn't match your array of months?

Comment: yes, exactly. you are correct

Comment: can I ask you why you are not using a simple ng-options ?

Comment: I am not able to match the mock-up across the browser including the hand holds. my client not accepting too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a directive to insert a **validator** into ngModelController

```
app.directive("listValidator", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
          var list = scope.$eval(attributes.listValidator);
          ngModel.$validators.listValidator = function(modelValue, viewValue) {  
              return list.indexOf(viewValue) !== -1;
          }
        },
    };
});
```

and then just tack it on to the control

```
<input 
    list-validator="months"
    ...
```

---

Updated plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/GUYUNQ0olqHkW3mdU1SP?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this in a slightly different way. Since you are using this input in a form, and you want to perhaps display some message and invalidate your form you may want to create a directive and add a custom validator with `ngModelController` and `$parsers`.

To do this we are going to create a directive and `require: ngModel`:

```
app.directive('validateMonth', [validateMonthFn]);

function validateMonthFn() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function linkFn(scope, element, attributes, ngModelController) {
      ngModelController.$parsers.unshift(function(value){
        if (value) {
          var valid = scope.months.indexOf(value) > -1;
          ngModelController.$setValidity('invalidInput', valid);
        }

        return valid ? valid : undefined;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your HTML you can simply add that directive to your existing input and if you wanted to display a message in addition:

```
<form name="monthForm">
  <input 
    validate-month
    type="text" 
    name="selectMonth" 
    id="selectMonth" 
    ng-model="defaultMonth"
    required
    ng-focus="showList=true"
    >
  <div ng-show="monthForm.selectMonth.$error.invalidInput">Please Select a Correct Month</div>

  <div>
    <ul ng-show="showList" ng-onmouseover="showList=true">
      <li ng-repeat="month in months" ng-click="setMonth(month)">{{month}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <input type="button" ng-disabled="monthForm.$invalid" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When you use ngModelController (via calling `require: ngModel`) in your directive, it gives you a lot of flexibility in choosing how you want to validate an input.

Besides this a simple `pattern=[]` attribute on the element could also suffice, but gives you less control over your validation.

Here is an updated [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0kx9EHdAvcccnk1xVKZh?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

As you can read [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input), there is the `[ng-pattern="string"]` directive for input elements.

This directive takes a regex expression to validate the input against.

I think google is your friend when searching for a regex that matches your valid months.

Another solution is to write your own validation as described [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms):

```
app.directive('validMonth', function($q, $timeout) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      var months = [
            "January", "February", "March", 
            "April", "May", "June", "July",  
            "August", "September", "October",
            "November", "December"
      ];

      ctrl.$asyncValidators.month = function(modelValue, viewValue) {

        if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
          // consider empty model valid
          return $q.when();
        }

        var def = $q.defer();

        $timeout(function() {
          // Mock a delayed response
          if (months.indexOf(modelValue) === -1) {
            // The month is valid
            def.resolve();
          } else {
            def.reject();
          }

        }, 2000);

        return def.promise;
      };
    }
  };
});
```

And the add this to your input `<input valid-month...`